# Styled component conditional rendering with interpolation is not applied

Tags: css, styled-components

I have the following styled component for the `selected` item.

```
${(props) =>
  props.selected &&
  css`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.selectedColor};
 `}
```

If I do following, it works,

```
 ${(props) =>
  props.selected &&
  css`
  background-color: lightblue;
  `}
```

However, with interpolation, it is not working. I tried the following, it is not working

```
${(props) =>
  props.selected &&
  `
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.selectedColor};
  `}
```

Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interpolating a function. Do this instead:

```
${(props) =>
   props.selected &&
   css`
      background-color: ${props.theme.colors.selectedColor};
   `}
```